# Contra konami code not working

Tags: contra

i have an emulated Contra on Jnes with a nes controller usb, and when i enter the Konami code, it doesn't work! Does anyone know how to help me? I've tried both B then A then B then A, and only B then A.

Answer (score 7):

The code in the original Contra is Up Up Down Down Left Right Left Right B A [Select] Start.

Select is only needed for a two-player game.

The code *must* be entered while the title graphic is scrolling on to the screen, which means you have to enter it quite quickly.

Comment: i still cant make it work, well i guess im gonna have to live without it :(

Answer (score -3):

I managed to make it work. I probably pressed both up and left when I pressed up, which made the code not work, but it worked the second time.